Google LSA notification not reaching Twilio number
I am building a software that forwards messages from Google Local Service Ads to my Twilio phone number and then have an AI autoresponder reply back.
It is working about 50% of the time, but the rest of the 50% my Twilio number is not receiving the notification, so the customer doesn't get a response back.
I contact Google and they said they are sending out all the notifications, so for some reason Twilio is not able to receive all of them.
Has anyone ran into an issue like this before?

Is there some code you want to share?
